# How to use "vanilla" WebWorker in React?

Tags: reactjs, web-worker

How do I use webworkers in a react app ?

I wrote an webworker and tested it in a simple app (html) so it works fine.

But using same approach in a react app doesnt work

I don't want at first use any react-something-webworker, I want just use pure Work api

```
const _worker = new Worker('./worker')
```

seems not importing the code inside worker.js file (self.addEventListener("message...)

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

In a React class component you can instantiate a web worker in `componentDidMount`, define the worker's `onmessage` and `onerror` methods, then call `worker.terminate()` in `componentWillUnmount`.

In a React function component, replace `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` with `useEffect`.

Your React component and your worker can then exchange messages with `postMessage`.

---

Even if you don't want to use any React-specific libraries, have a look at the code from the [react-hooks-worker](https://github.com/dai-shi/react-hooks-worker) library. It's less than 100 LOC and it will help you understand how to use the Web Worker API.

Comment: I'm using function react approach. I solved it using worker loader and app-rewired due to my app was created with create-react-app and if I not mistaken it put webpack inside of another place and I shouldn't edit it directly. So I used app rewired to overload  webpack and use worker loader. I didint understand well what worker loader does but worked fine.  I appreciate If anybody could clarify this for me